# I need to compute an asymptotic approximation to this improper integral using the method of stationary phase.

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals

I need to compute an asymptotic approximation to this improper integral using the method of stationary phase.
$$I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{0}{({-\xi})^{1.5k}\sin{(\xi{t_{0})}}e^{-i\xi{x}}}d\xi,\:\:\:\text{as 
}x\to+\infty$$

where $t_{0}$ and $k$ are constants with respect to the variable of integration.

I have attempted this and I am getting a result that seems to diverge probably due to the $-\infty$ limit:

$$I(x)\approx\lim_{a\to-\infty}\left[\frac{(-a)^{1.5k}\sin(at_{0})}{ix}\right]$$
It looks like I am doing something wrong, kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For what values of $t_0$ and $k$ does your integral converge?

Comment: $t_{0}\in[0,\infty)$ and $k$ is an index of a series running from $0$ to $\infty$. The problem is actually a double integral involving the Mittag-Leffler function, this is just an extract from the problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure the integrals diverge for such values of $k$. This should follow from repeated integration by parts.

Comment: What do I do? Do I relax some conditions on k?